# is extending mxml component with from another mxml component with visual child supported behavior in flex 4?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I've been trying to create a custom mxml component that extends another custom mxml component (i.e. MyMXMLComponent -> BaseMXMLComponent -> Group).

I've been reading that trying to add visual children to MyMXMLComponent caused error with Flex 3 but that's no longer the case with Flex 4.

What I want to know is whether this is a supported/fixed/documented feature of Flex 4? or just some undefined behavior in Flex 4 that may get changed with future updates?

if this is supported and documented feature, does anyone have link pointing to adobe document stating it as such?

Comment: You just want to extend the functionality of some custom component?

Comment: no i wanted to write a base class that layout some base visual elements and write a child class that add additional visual elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure is supported in Flex 4.  You need to use the [DefaultProperty](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf680e1-7ffe.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7a29) metadata tag on a public property of your custom component.

It's as easy as that :)

Comment: why do I need to use the DefaultProperty?

Comment: Well, depending on how you're doing/creating it, you might need to specify it since all nested tags will be bound to that default property.  Since you're extending Group, those children will just get added to the component as visual children.  If you want to do something else with it however, you can use the metadata to override the original one and do more things.  If you're extending Group, it's fine, it'll just be added to the display list.

Comment: ok.. well i don't think I need to use DefaultProperty in my case. do you know if there's adobe documentation somewhere that states that this is a supported behavior now?

Comment: It is supported, if you're extending Group, it'll be added to the display list.

Comment: alright i guess i will take your word for it.. it would be nice if adobe was clear about stuff like these...